# How to sort the data according to the highest accuracy of results in elasticsearch using spring data

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

Hey I need to set in default searching elasticsearch sorting by highest accuracy of results how implement it by using spring data elasticsearch, spring data boot ?

Here is example code where I would like to add this:

```
boolean issetPriceFrom = Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getPriceFrom()).isPresent();
        boolean issetPriceTo = Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getPriceTo()).isPresent();

        final List<FilterBuilder> filters = Lists.newArrayList();
        final NativeSearchQueryBuilder searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withQuery(matchAllQuery());

        Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getBuyer()).ifPresent(v -> filters.add(boolFilter().must(termFilter("buyer", v))));
        Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getCat()).ifPresent(v -> filters.add(boolFilter().must(termFilter("cat", v))));
        Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getComment_type()).ifPresent(v -> filters.add(boolFilter().must(termFilter("comment_type", v))));
        Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getItem()).ifPresent(v -> filters.add(boolFilter().must(termFilter("item", v))));
        Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getSeller()).ifPresent(v -> filters.add(boolFilter().must(termFilter("seller", v))));
        Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getTree_cat()).ifPresent(v -> filters.add(boolFilter().must(termFilter("tree_cat", v))));

        final BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = new BoolQueryBuilder();

        //access for many sellers
        if (searchParams.getSellers() != null) {
//            Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getSellers().split(",")).ifPresent(v -> {
//                filters.add(boolFilter().must(termsFilter("seller", v)));
//            });

            for (String user : searchParams.getSellers().split(",")) {
                boolQueryBuilder.must(queryStringQuery(user).field("seller"));
            }
        }

        //access for many categories
        if (searchParams.getCats() != null) {
//            Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getCats().split(",")).ifPresent(v -> {
//                filters.add(boolFilter().must(termsFilter("cat", v)));
//            });
            for (String category : searchParams.getCats().split(",")) {
                boolQueryBuilder.must(queryStringQuery(category).field("cat"));
            }
        }

        if (Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getTitle()).isPresent()) {
            boolQueryBuilder.must(queryStringQuery(searchParams.getTitle()).analyzeWildcard(true).field("title"));
        }

        if (Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getComment_text()).isPresent()) {
            boolQueryBuilder.must(queryStringQuery(searchParams.getComment_text()).analyzeWildcard(true).field("comment_text"));
        }

        if (issetPriceFrom || issetPriceTo) {
            filters.add(rangeFilter("price").from(searchParams.getPriceFrom()).to(searchParams.getPriceTo()));
        }

        if (Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getTsFrom()).isPresent()
                || Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getTsTo()).isPresent()) {
            filters.add(rangeFilter("ts").from(searchParams.getTsFrom()).to(searchParams.getTsTo()));
        }

        if (hasComments != null && hasComments.equals(true)) {
            filters.add(FilterBuilders.boolFilter().must(FilterBuilders.existsFilter("comment_text")));
        }

        if (hasComments != null && hasComments.equals(false)) {
            filters.add(FilterBuilders.boolFilter().must(FilterBuilders.missingFilter("comment_text")));
        }

        searchQuery.withQuery(boolQueryBuilder);
        FilterBuilder[] filterArr = new FilterBuilder[filters.size()];
        filterArr = filters.toArray(filterArr);
        searchQuery.withFilter(andFilter(filterArr));

        if (pageable != null) {
            searchQuery.withPageable(pageable);
        }

        return searchQuery;
```

I would be grateful if I got even a piece of code that could implement.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use `withSort` method.Use it like this:

```
SortBuilder sortBuilder = SortBuilders.fieldSort(fieldName).order(SortOrder.ASC)

    NativeSearchQueryBuilder builder = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withQuery(matchAllQuery())
            .withSort(sortBuilder)
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: hmmm I had more in mind if I'm not mistaken , " score " the idea is to make the data sortwane by as if most valuable

Comment: If I am not wrong , by default  ES fetches gets the result sorted by score.